# Is there a way in notepad++ to turn on word wrap for specific file types

Tags: notepad++, word-wrap

When using notepad++, I want my .xml files to have word wrap turned on, while keeping it off for all my other files. Is this possible/is there a plugin for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try other editor [SynWrite](http://uvviewsoft.com/synwrite/). In the Options dialog, "Editor overrides" tab, you ll see option to override word wrap for any file type.

Comment: [Cool](http://uvviewsoft.com/synwrite/images/MCarets.gif) notepad++ replacement. Never heard of it but I'm instantly impressed.

Comment: This may be a good alternative, but it doesn't really answer the original question..